# Can CSS be dynamic and recognize the size of another div?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two divs that are set next to each other. One on the left, like a menu. And another on the right where all of my content will be.

However, my menu is only 300px long. After 300px, all of the posts start to fall under my menu and no longer aligned with the rest of the content that is inside my content div.

This is the CSS for my menu.

```
#menu {
   border-right: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
   border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   font-size: 12px;
   height: 300px;
   line-height: 22px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0 20px 20px;
   width: 155px;
}
```

How can I make the above menu length grow as the page grows.

My main content div is a div that also capsulated my menu div. 
Each entry then falls in its own div that has the following style

```
.grid {
  border-right: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 480px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 155px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Once the grid gets passed the 300px. It falls below my menu. How do I prevent this?

Keep in mind, as much as Id like to change the order of these divs, I cant. Im using wordpress.com to host this site and they will only allow me to modify my css. So, as long as I can do it through the CSS, we are good. Otherwise, I have to find another way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do as in this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/x6BqB/)**

Use `display:table-cell;` instead of `display:table-block;`

Also remove `float:left;` from both `#menu` and `.grid`

**Note: `display: table-cell;` will work on all browsers except below IE 8**

Answer (score 0):

I hope you looking you can this :- http://tinkerbin.com/OUJfyPhs

You can achive your desired results with the use `display:table-cell;` in both div's.

See your updated **CSS**

```
#menu {
border-right: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
display: table-cell;
font-size: 12px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 20px 20px;
width: 155px;
background:yellow;
}

.grid {
border-right: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
border-top: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
background:red;
padding: 20px;
display: table-cell;
width: 155px;
height:560px;
}
```

Comment: That didnt work. Here is your example modified to better show my issue, notice how after the first post all the content falls bellow the menu.
http://tinkerbin.com/4Rljp0F1

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this works

```
#main{
height:100%;
height:auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can wrap them both in containers, like this: http://tinkerbin.com/KA8dwfji